# get a message home

Tags: idiom-meaning

In the song *A Message* by Coldplay, Chris Martin sings:

> And I’m not gonna take it back
>
> And I’m not gonna say I don’t mean that
>
> You’re the target that I’m aiming at
>
> And I’ll get that message home

Context: http://timeline.coldplay.com/lyrics/a-message/

What does *get that message home* mean? Especially the ''idiom'' *get home*?

Comment: They're song lyrics.. for all we know the lyricist was high and that's all he could come up with. To me, though, it seems like he wants his "message" to be understood.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom is not "get home". it is "to get something home". More commonly this is expressed as "to drive something home".

> **drive your message/point home**
>
> to state something in a very forceful and effective way:
>
> *The speaker really drove his message home, repeating his main point several times.*
>
> Cambridge Dictionary Online

The original expression was "to drive a point home". This metaphor refers to driving a nail into a piece of wood or a peg into a hole. It connects with the idea of making a point in an argument. Note that 'home' means 'rightful place'.

The expression "to get a message home" is two steps away from the original idea.

EDIT
This answer was posted simultaneously with others. I see that there is some overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a definition of home](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/home).

It's probably closest to this usage:

> **drive** (or **hammer** or **press** or **ram**) **something home**
>
> Make something clearly understood by the use of repeated or forcefully direct arguments
>
> Example sentences:
>
> - we must drive home the message that crime doesn’t pay
> - New Labour relied on its supporters in the trade union leadership to ram that message home.
> - He was confident, he was direct, he drove his points home.
> - Depriving us of the end of the story renders it difficult for him to drive home the central theme of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a variant on the idiom *[bring home](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring+home)*

> to make unmistakably clear

*Merriam-Webster*

In context, is seems that the speaker is trying to emphasize that he is reaffirming his message, he is sincere, and he will get the listener to understand his intentions.